# Multiple program execution in selenium webdriver is not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Multiple program execution in selenium WebDriver is not working. I written one testNG xml file and 2 java classes. I tried to ran those two java classes from the xml file. But it's not working.

XML Code:

```
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="SIT">
    <classes>
      <class name="testng1.NewTest"/>
      <class name="testng1.NewTest2"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Now "NewTest.java" class:

```
package testng1;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class NewTest {
    public static WebDriver driver;
  @BeforeTest
  public void launch()
  {
      System.setProperty("WebDriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\rprem\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
      driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
      System.out.println("BeforeTest Method");
  }
@Test
public void gmail()
{
    driver.get("https://gmail.com");
    System.out.println("Gmail was launched");
}
@AfterTest
public void quit()
{
    driver.quit();
    System.out.println("AfterTest Method");
}
}
```

Now "NewTest2.java" :

```
package testng1;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class NewTest2 extends NewTest
{
@Test
public void yahoo()
{
    driver.get("https://yahoo.com");
    System.out.println("yahoo site was opened");
}
}
```

When I ran the xml file using testng,I got below error message:

Error Message:

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest launch
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more
>   information, see
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver.
>   The latest version can be downloaded from
>   http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
>         at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService.access$000(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:32)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:167)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setupService(InternetExplorerDriver.java:288)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:210)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:154)
>         at testng1.NewTest.launch(NewTest.java:13)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:626)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
>         at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
>
> ```
> SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest quit
> SKIPPED: gmail
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more
> ```
>
> information, see
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver.
>   The latest version can be downloaded from
>   http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
>         at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService.access$000(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:32)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:167)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setupService(InternetExplorerDriver.java:288)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:210)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:154)
>         at testng1.NewTest.launch(NewTest.java:13)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:626)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
>         at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
>
> ```
> SKIPPED: gmail
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more
> ```
>
> information, see
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver.
>   The latest version can be downloaded from
>   http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
>         at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService.access$000(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:32)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:167)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setupService(InternetExplorerDriver.java:288)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:210)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:154)
>         at testng1.NewTest.launch(NewTest.java:13)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:626)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
>         at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
>
> ```
> SKIPPED: yahoo
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more
> ```
>
> information, see
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver.
>   The latest version can be downloaded from
>   http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
>         at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService.access$000(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:32)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:167)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setupService(InternetExplorerDriver.java:288)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:210)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:154)
>         at testng1.NewTest.launch(NewTest.java:13)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:626)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
>         at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)

```
===============================================
    testng1
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 3
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================


===============================================
practice by packages
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 3
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

Comment: Check this out , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946478/how-to-set-path-for-executable-ie-11-drivers

Comment: thanks Sudha. It's working fine now but "gmail" method is getting executed twice. I didn't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this below line from your `xml` file. Because your Class `NewTest2 extends NewTest` So, no need to write here.

```
<class name="testng1.NewTest"/>
```

Replace your `xml` file, with this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite guice-stage="DEVELOPMENT" name="Test">
 <test verbose="2" name="Dummy">    
    <classes>
             <class name="testng1.NewTest2"/> 
    </classes>
 </test> 
</suite>
```

Before going to execute your script inside `IE Browser`, please correct these settings.

> Go to settings -> Internet options -> Security tab -> Make this option
>   Enable for all four zones. (Enable Protected Mode)

Refer below Image for change this settings.

[image]

Your code of execution will be like this.

[image]

Execution:- if you run above xml file, your code will execute this way.

1) BeforeTest Method 
2) Gmail 
3) Yahoo 
4) AfterTest Method

Comment: HI Janish, Yes I tried. But still same result. GMAIL is running twice

Comment: Try to run your script through xml file.

Comment: did it..but same result. Some where I'm missing logic

Comment: Please request you to replace your xml file with my and try to run your test case with xml file. It will surely work for you. :)

Comment: Hello I am done with my code and I have updated my answer as well. Please check my answer and update me. Now my script is working in all browsers.