# Clicking <input> type (selenium) causing issues

Tags: java, selenium

this is a strange one (for me) that I can't get my head around.

I have an application, I recorded a basic test with the Selenium IDE and exported this and have tried to make the code more robust.  I am having issues with this element:

```
<input class=" " id="P400_ADD_MEDIUM_BUT" onclick="void(0);" type="button" value="Add Emission">
```

It should be fairly simple, it has an id so initially I thought I would use this to locate the element and click it:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("P400_ADD_MEDIUM_BUT")).click();
```

When I watch the test run, the button is highlighted blue (this application has a two stage blue colour, dark blue when the mouse button is down, lighter blue when mouse released) - the colour I see is light blue - however, nothing happens (a popup should appear.)

I have tried changing this to XPath and using the following:
//input[@id='P400_ADD_MEDIUM_BUT']

> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='P400_ADD_MEDIUM_BUT']")).click();

But still the same result.
I played the recorded script back in the IDE and this works fine.  I should mention that the test has to run in IE (it's an internal application and IE is the only browser used internally) - but I am stumped.

IE is 11, latest selenium and IE driver.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: When you refresh the page, Your `id` attribute value is getting changed?

Comment: The id is staying constant - I have refreshed and checked before and after and the line never changes.

Comment: can you share the html of the section that contains this button? also you should share the exact error, is not visible / is not clickable / is not found or what kind of error, the error is important in detecting the root cause.

Comment: There is no error - nothing at all - just the behaviour as described.

Comment: As far as I understand selenium clicks button successfully, but nothing happens. It's possible that javascript action is not already bound to this button when selenium attempt to click it. Try to wait some time after `driver.get()` before you execute your `click();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of these below code.

**Note:-** Before going to click this button, provide few seconds of wait So your driver may able to find the webelement.

For wait I am using `Explicit Wait` method.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='button'][@value='Add Emission']"))));   //Wait for 60 seconds.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='button'][@value='Add Emission']")).click();
```

> OR

Try to click on button using `Javascript Executor` method.

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='button'][@value='Add Emission']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

Comment: It seems like your IE Browser settings needs to be changed, so before going to Run my script, Please modify settings this way.. refer this Answer...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234351/multiple-program-execution-in-selenium-webdriver-is-not-working/46235397#46235397

Comment: Setting protected and running it via JavascriptExecutor seems to have done the trick